# Why is my water (bladder) tank empty with air in my lines?

Tags: water, well-pump

I have a submerged water well pump. It is more than 100 ft deep. My water tank is not filling up and I have air in my lines. I have noticed a big jump in my power use also. Today I turned on the water and nothing but air came out. I went out to the faucet located at the pump and got only air also. Then I tried the pump faucet again and got water and air. Any information would be a big help.

Comment: It sounds like low water level in the well.  Would turn off the well pump for at least a day, and then turn it back on and see if that helps.  Are you in a dry area?  Could also be the pump needing maintenance or replacement.

Comment: Little detail to b certain, but @crip659 is probably on the right track. What does the pressure gauge say? I would guess the high power use is from the pump not shutting off as it can't build pressure - either due to lack of water in the well or some other problem.

Comment: I have to agree with @crip659, you're pumping air. It's bad, because it puts a load on a pump that's expecting to be water cooled. You could burn it out if it keeps operating pumping air.   You need a well guy out to check the water levels in your well, both static (not being pumped) and dynamic while being pumped after a few minutes.

Comment: One more comment...most wells, at least in my neck of the woods have records with the County or State as to the depth of the well and the production rate.  Getting those records can help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: I agree with a low water level but it  could be a cracked line if there is not a torque arrestor the twisting of the pump can crack the poly line I have seen this also , if you haven’t pumped any water out for a day the well would have refilled in most areas unless you are in the south west I have heard that the main reservoirs are are low with the drought, but no problems in the Pacific Northwest, a 100’ well is not a deep one so there must be shallow water normally.